# How can i change color of a specific LinearLayout's child in Recyclerview's onCreateViewHolder in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

[image]

I want to make a RecyclerView like the image above.

it's kind of ranking and only top 5's color of rank is red dynamically.

and I made a view XML which has two TextView for RecyclerView's ViewHolder. one is number and the other is singer's name.

specifically, I only want to change the color of the numbers.

so I thought I could find its child by using LinearLayout and take out a specific child.

and I wanted to change the child view's color in onCreateViewHolder in RecyclerView's Adapter.

Because ViewHolder is created and inflated in onCreateViewHolder method.

so I thought I have to change the view's color in onCreateViewHolder.

but it wasn't easy and simple.

in the onCreateViewHolder method, it returns Viewholder, but I made a LinearLayout,

and I added a view that changed its color. and I tried to return the LinearLayout,

I know it's not gonna work, but I don't know how to make it.

this is my code.

1.RecyclerView Adapter

```
class SingerListAdapter(private val singers : ArrayList<Singer>) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return singers.size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val layout = LinearLayout(parent.context)
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val viewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item, parent, false) as ViewGroup
    //first child of viewGroup
    val view = viewGroup.getChildAt(0) as TextView //the TextView of ranking number
    view.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(parent.context, R.color.red))
    layout.addView(view)

    return layout //i can't return linearLayout
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

}

class SingerViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

 } 
}
```

2.view XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_rank"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:hint="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_singer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/view_rank"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_rank"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_rank"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:hint="ITZY"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try if this works (I can't test it, so if it fails I'll delete my post... it's just that writing this as a comment is cumbersome):

```
class SingerListAdapter(private val singers : ArrayList<Singer>) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
   return singers.size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SingerViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    return SingerViewHolder(inflater, parent)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SingerViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if(position < 5) {
      holder.rankTv.setTextColor(Color.RED)
    }
    else {
      holder.rankTv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    }
}

class SingerViewHolder(view : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val rankTv = view.findViewById(R.id.view_rank)
 } 
}
```

Whether it works or not, the basic idea is to check the position of the item in `onBindViewHolder` and if it's `< 5` (i.e. it's in your top 5), then you get the `TextView` for the rank from your `holder` and change its color. I'm not sure if the `else` case is required.

Edit: Most of the time you don't have to do anthing in `onCreateViewHolder` and `getItemCount` apart from the standard stuff. Usually your work goes into `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: I already did something like you wrote, and it worked well !! but I want to do kind of that thing in onCreateViewHolder, not onBindViewHolder, because i think in onBindViewHolder , the datas is just allocated, and view is created in onCreateViewHolder, so..i want to do that function in onCreateViewHolder, but i'm really appreciated for your answer! thank you!

Comment: I would advice against that. The purpose of `onCreateViewHolder` is to simply construct the `ViewHolder` objects (it basically calls the constructor of your `SingerViewHolder` class). If you still want to work that way, in my opinion you should write the code in the constructor of your `SingerViewHolder`. Nonetheless I think that doing it in `onBindViewHolder` is the correct way to go about it. Good luck.

Comment: I wonder if i change color of the view in onCreaeViewHolder or onBindViewHolder. when the ViewHolder is created in onCreateViewHolder(), System measures view's size and locates the view and draw view. and in this process, the color will be already changed, and the data is allocated later. but if i change the color after the data is allocated, i feel like the process order is not good. because in onCreateViewHolder, System measures view's size, location, draw, and then change color and allocate data in onBindViewHolder or SingerViewHolder. which one is better? i'm a newbie in Android System.

Comment: so can you tell me about this? it doesn't matter the order that i told ??

Comment: It doesn't matter, but like I said I would do it in `onBindViewHolder` because it's easier to determine the position.